# How to correctly understand measureed JMeter PerfMon plugin CPU percentage?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, cpu, metrics, jmeter-plugins

I have question about ***JMeter PerfMon plugin*** which is measuring percentage use of CPU which my *Dropwizard* app is consuming. Important things to mention:

- Operating system is ***Linux Fedora 31 64-bit OS***.
- I have **Intel i5-4200U CPU @ 1.60GHz x 4** processor on my DELL laptop computer
- I'm running both **client and server** on **SAME device**
- I run jmeter-server in order to be able to collect Dropwizard-Metrics via JMX by running `java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=4711 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=4711  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -jar ./target/DW-Bookshop-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar server config.yml` command
- I run downloaded ServerAgent-2.2.3 via `./startAgent.sh` command so graphs for PerfMon plugin can be generated

When I run **Concurrency Thread Group (CTG)** load test as defined here:
[image: Concurrency Thread Group for Dropwizard app]

...I get this graph generated for PerfMon plugin:

[image: JMeter's PerfMon plugin graph view of CPU and Disks I/O]

What bothers me is **HOW CAN violet** color line (**CPU DWApp-CPU%**) be going OVER 400 when my machine has 4 Logical CPUs (as my Intel processor supports hyper-threading)? Please note that I've also set PID value to measure ONLY Dropwizard's app CPU percentage usage in `Metric parameter` field.

Any help/suggestion is more than welcome.